# Method for navigating from subpages to main page and scroll to id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m not that good with coding, so I decided to ask here. Maybe anyone could give solution for what I have.

Problem - I have 1 navigation link on my main page which scrolls to id using jQuery. It works and everything, but only when on main page. All subpages have this link on navigation and I would like to ask, how to, when link is clicked on every page which is not main page, to navigate it back to main page and then execute scrolling instead of nothing happening on subpage? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
jQuery(function() {
    //catch all clicks on a tags
    jQuery("a").click(function(e){
        //check if it has a hash
        if(this.hash){
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);
            var $toElement = jQuery("[id="+hash+"]");
            var width=jQuery(window).width();
            var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top;

        //scroll to element
            jQuery("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop : toPosition
            },2000);
            // return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //do the same with urls with hash too
    if(location.hash){
        var hash = location.hash;

        jQuery("a[href="+hash+"]").click();
    }
});
```